# Access Node-Webkit App from other Application

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Is it possible to call a function in nodewebkit from an external application?

For example. I would like to decide whether the window is hidden or show through a external application or with applescript.

Comment: On initial execution or after its running?

Comment: After running. I would like to have it in the background and make it active when i require.

Comment: Maybe you can use a socket.io server as a service bus between applications (your node-webkit app and the external app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiarized with the applescript language, but is possible between languages that have an implemented library for `socket.io`

Using `socket.io` you can behave between applications, `socket.io` act like an node.js `EventEmitter` (or pubsub), clients can send events and suscribe to those events in real-time.

For your case you can create a socket.io server with `node.js`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  // Listens the 'control-hide' event
  socket.on('control-hide', function () {
      // Emit for all connected sockets, the node-webkit app knows hot to handle it
      io.emit('hide');
  });

  // Listens the 'control-show' event
  socket.on('control-show', function () {
      // Emit for all connected sockets, the node-webkit app knows hot to handle it
      io.emit('show');
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And add a [socket.io client](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client) to your node-webkit application

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000'); // I will assume that the server is in the same machine

socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connected');
});

// Listens the 'hide' event
socket.on('hide', function(){
  // hide window
});

// Listens the 'show' event
socket.on('show', function(){
  // show window
});
```

And for this example I will assume that another javascript application will control the "show" and "hide" operations

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000'); // I will assume that the server is in the same machine

socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connected');
});

// sends a 'control-show' event to the server
function show() {
  socket.emit('control-show');
}

// sends a 'control-hide' event to the server
function hide() {
  socket.emit('control-hide');
}
```